# Is it possible to add the citation information in the List of Figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, citing

Since I use pictures in my Bachelor's Thesis that are not originated from me, I would like to put the citation information, e.g. a website link, into the list of figures (the bottom block is important). 
So basically I'd like to have something like this:
[image]

I could not find a way online. Currently I display my image like this:

```
    \begin{figure}
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{~/Dropbox/Thesis/multi_layer_perceptron.jpg}
         \caption{Schematic View of a Multilayer Perceptron}
         \label{fig:mlp}
    \end{figure}
```

and the list of figures like this: `\listoffigures`. Resulting in:
[image]

Maybe I am just too unexperienced. So, what would be the Tex way to do that? :)

EDIT:
Thanks to the post from @John Kormylo I found this solution: 
`\caption[Schematic View of a Multilayer Perceptron\newline{Image retrieved from }\url{https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tensorflow/tensorflow\_multi\_layer\_perceptron\_learning} (Visited on 08/06/2019)]`

Which results in:
[image]
I am rather content, but I still hope for a easier and better looking way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can input a separate caption for the LOF as an optional argument.  `\protect` is used to prevent the macro from expanding until ready to print.  Even when not needed, it makes the aux file shorter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\begin{figure}
   \includegraphics{example-image-A}
   \caption[\protect\hypertarget{lof.\thefigure}{}LOF version of caption
       \newline Available from \protect\url{www.elfsoft2000.com}]
    {Caption with link to LOF (see \hyperlink{lof.\thefigure}{Figure \thefigure})}
   \label{fig:mlp}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
   \includegraphics{example-image-B}
   \caption[Caption with footnote\protect\footnote{\protect\url{www.elfsoft2000.com}}]
     {Normal Caption}
   \label{fig:mlp}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```